# What is wrong with my code is not calling the function, JSP

Tags: javascript, function, jsp

I am trying to get an alert if I left an empty field but It doesn't work, it just go to the next step without calling the function. I forgot to put the "onsubmit="return validation()"

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
            <script type =text/javascript>
                function validation() {

                        var errormessage = "";

                    if (document.getElementById('firstName').value == "") {
                        errormessage += "please enter the firstname \n";
                        document.getElementById("firstName").style.borderColor =            "red";

                    }

    if (errormessage != "") {

                    alert(errormessage);
                    return false;

                }

            }
        </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action ="anotherpage.jsp" method="post" autocomplete="on"      onsubmit="return validation()>
                  Firstname:<input type="text" id="firstName" name="name" value= "            <%=name%>"  />
              <br>



         <input type="submit" value="Next Step" name="nextStep" />
         </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Well, you never call `validation()` anywhere.

Comment: Also, you need to prevent the default behavior of the `submit` button if you don't want it to automatically move on

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put "onsubmit="return validation()"... to call the function, it was in my code I just forgot to put in here. still doesnt work.

Comment: Hey @CarlosSiverio please see my answer below and let me know if it worked or not, so I may post you with better solution and explanation thanks

Answer (score 0):

please add inverted commas also in script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Hey you are not calling validation function

replace this inside your form

```
Firstname:<input type="text" id="firstName" name="name" value= "<%=name%>"  />
```

with this and test again

```
  Firstname:<input type="text" id="firstName" name="name" onsubmit="return validation();" value= "<%=name%>"/>
```

Comment: onsubmit attribute is called before your form is submitted to server, in this function you should call your client side validation function

Comment: if validation function will return true then your form will be submitted otherwise it will not be submitted

Comment: add an alert in top of validation function to check if its working or not]

Comment: Thx I actually put  onsubmit="return validation(); inside form tag and I did aswell with the code you gave me, the field turns red.. but it still going on.

Comment: try removing + from this line errormessage += "please enter the firstname \n";